# Proof regarding parity, and rational numbers in lowest terms

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, solution-verification, proof-writing

Suppose s = $\frac{e}{f}$ and also $s = \frac{a}{b} + \frac{c}{d} = \frac{ad+bc}{bd}$, where all the fractions are written in lowest terms...then am I okay in assuming that, given
$\frac{e}{f}$ = $\frac{ad+bc}{db}$, I can safely equate $f=db$ to prove a fact about the parity of the two? It seems to me that since the fractions are irreducible, it's an okay assumption to make, but I've been looking at proofs for way too long and at this point I'm not really sure of myself...and help would be appreciated!

** I should clarify that I'm not really concerned with whether or not f is actually equal to db, but more whether or not I can assume that they have the same parity

Comment: Unfortunately this does not always work. Counterexample: $s=\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{8}{16}$, but $2\neq 16$.

Comment: It's not even true that parity is conserved.  $\frac 13=\frac 16+\frac 16=\frac {12}{36}$ for example.